# Am I allowed to re-enter the US using an emergency Australian passport?

Tags: usa, us-visa-waiver-program, australian-citizens

Unfortunately my Australian passport was stolen on New Year's, and as such I am now in possession of an emergency passport, which is not eligible for an ESTA.

Travel plans see me travelling to Mexico this week. However, with no ESTA I won't be allowed back into the States without a valid visa.

Does anyone have any advice or experience with this? The only option I can see is applying for a visa while in Mexico; however, I feel processing times will be too long.

I'm hoping there is some provision that helps me out as I am not leaving North America.

Comment: You will certainly want to consider cancelling your trip to Mexico.

Comment: Are you entering Mexico via land or air?

Comment: Can you not get 48 hour turnaround on renewal?  And what did the consulate say when they issued you with a  PTD?

Comment: You can't "renew" a stolen passport.  You need to apply for a new passport, which requires things like birth certificates and photos signed by specific people which I'm guessing are not available to the person at this time.

Comment: @Doc Yeah .. renew was the wrong word.  But as the OP seems to have a PTD he already should have discussed his situation with the appropriate people.  And I can't following the process on the Oz gov website

Comment: @PeterM the ETD would be issued by Australia, who have no authority to issue or transfer visas or authorizations issued by the US.  The OP is referring to the US ESTA, which isn't valid on a ETD, and they have no visa, so reentry to the US is now problematic.

Comment: Moo That is correct, unfortunately due to Emergancy's being non e-passports, they are not illegible for the ESTA.

Doc The plan was to fly however driving isnt out of the question as Tijuana is quite close to the border

A full passport won;t be available until i am in my home country

Comment: Is it possible to still receive in I-94 form at the airport?

Comment: @Moo I understand all that.  But the OP should have had a discussion with the Oz consulate as to what the PTD allows them to do.

Comment: @PeterM That discussion has been had. Simply put, the PTD is not illegible for a ESTA and i would need to get a visa to enter the States, but HOWEVER since i am already in the United States it is a bit tricky, as i cannot get a visa for the united states while already in the united states.

The Aus consulate has no influence or say in this matter

Comment: Traveling by land excuses you from having to apply for an ESTA, but **not from the other VWP requirements**. Having an e-passport is a requirement for entering under the VWP at all and not specific to ESTA, so going by land wouldn't help you.

Comment: @Ham I think the word you are looking for in your comments is "eligible" :)

Comment: I do mean eligible haha, grammer hasnt been my strong point today (nor has it been consistant).

@HenningMakholm Thankyou for mentioning that, I completely overlooked that fact. So at this stage the only way is to successfully obtain a Visa.

Answer (score 2):

As best as the community can determine, no special provision exists to permit you to visit Mexico (or Canada) under these circumstances.  This means that unless you have high confidence of getting a visa issued in time while you are in Mexico, that you are best to suspend your Mexico travel plans.

It is possible that a US border officer would let you in, given your circumstances, but it is a risk that I wouldn't suggest taking.